# How to get the bet in the play method?

Tags: java, input

I'm writing a poker game and finished the Card class, deck Class, checkHands class. Now I'm working on the play class. I defined two static variable at the beginning and three data fields:

```
 private static final int startingBalance=100;
 private static final int numberOfCards=5;

 // holding current poker 5-card hand, balance, bet    
private List<Card> currentHand;
private int balance;
private int bet;
```

Then, my question is how to get the value of bet depending on the users' input?

```
 bet = input?
```

Comment: What have you tried? What tools do you have at your disposal? Are you familiar with scanner objects?

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in)
int bet=scanner.nextInt();
```

[JAVA SE7 Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `switch case` for different inputs provided by the user.
eg.
You can ask the user

```
enter 1 to bid 
enter 2 to fold
```

and on ,
then use

```
case 1:
// what ever you wanna do
and on..
```

you can read about switch [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)